# Laravel как использовать два внешних ключа к одной таблице при работе с моделями

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Доброго времени суток.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как работать с моделью, которая имеет два внешних ключа к одной таблице. Суть примерно такова:

Таблица *Commands*

- id
- command_name

Таблица *Matches*

- id
- match_date
- match_time
- command_first (FK Commands.id)
- command_second (FK Commands.id)

И сам вопрос, как из модели **Match** получить доступ к двум моделям **Command**?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Две связи - на первый и на второй ключ. В чем проблема?

Comment: @InDevX я не понию как получить экземпляры моделей Command, связи установлены. Связь  1 ко многим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используется foreign в котором указываешь название столбца и название столбца с котором хочешь сделать связь ну и саму таблицу.

$table->string('command_first');          $table->foreign('command_first')->references('id')->on('Commands')->cascadeOnDelete();